# Anderson Higgs mechanism and superconducting phase fluctuations

Tags: gauge-theory, superconductivity, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In the context of superconductivity, in the Anderson Higgs mechanism (see, for instance, https://doi.org/10.1119/1.5093291 ([PDF](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10096479)), or https://doi.org/10.21468/SciPostPhysLectNotes.11 ([PDF](https://scipost.org/SciPostPhysLectNotes.11/pdf)), the gauge-invariant quantity $A^\mu+\partial^\mu\theta$, (proportional to the Noether current corresponding to the global U(1) symmetry breaking), acquires a mass. Here $A^\mu$ is the electromagnetic four-potential, and $\theta$ is the phase of the superconducting order parameter $\Delta=|\Delta|e^{-i\theta}$. This is used to explain the decay of magnetic field inside a superconductor.

Would it also lead to a suppression of superconducting phase fluctuations (time and space dependent fluctuations/variations) of the phase $\theta$? In practice, say, I have a system with some specified electric and magnetic fields, and then I fix the gauge using some gauge-fixing condition for convenience. This completely fixes the four-potential $A^\mu$. Now, does the system exhibit/permit fluctuations in the phase $\theta$? It seems that the mass term should lead to exponential damping of any random fluctuation, both in space and time. We thus end up with the saddle-point solution obtained from the Lagrangian (considering the electromagnetic term $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ too) with no additional fluctuations.